# function not working on html input change (Flask)?

Tags: python, html, postgresql, flask

**I'm trying to make function work on web page when edit date inputs, but it can't work, and I can't know the reason, HTML code**

```
    <form action="{{ url_for('top_agencies')}}" onchange="top_agencies()">
    <input type="date" name="begin"
    placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" value=""
    min="2013-01-01" max="2030-12-31">

<input type="date" name="end"
    placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" value=""
    min="2013-01-01" max="2030-12-31">

<script>
function top_agencies() {
    // Get the value of the date input
    var begin = document.getElementById("begin").value;
    var end = document.getElementById("end").value;

    // Make a POST request to the /top_agencies endpoint
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "{{ url_for('top_agencies') }}");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("begin=" + begin + "&end=" + end);
}
</script>
```

**and that are Flask functions**

```
@app.route('/top_agencies', methods=['POST'])

def top_agencies():
    # Get the value of the date input
    begin = request.form["begin"]
    end = request.form["end"]

    # Get the top agencies for the given date
    result = get_top_agencies(begin, end)

    # Render the top agencies template
    return render_template("top_agencies.html", result=result)

def get_top_agencies(begin, end):
    result = {any thing}
    return result
```

**thanks for help**

Comment: well for one you didn't close your `form` tag with `</form>`. i would start with checking the console log on your browser to see what it tells you

Comment: sorry, I closed it but didn't write it here

Comment: The `onchange` should be inside the input tags, not the form tag.

Comment: I tried that, but the function didn't work also